# sorting a List in java

Tags: java, sorting

i have a list of objects that i wanna sort, i create this list by providing an existing list first then than complete my list by adding other objects like this

```
    Client c = service.getClientById(idClient);
    Commande pc = null;
    List<Commande> commandes = new ArrayList<Commande>(c.getCommandes());

    for(Paiement i : c.getPaiements()){
        pc = new Commande();
        pc.setClient(c);
        pc.setDate(i.getDate());
        pc.setMethode(i.getMethode());
        pc.setPayee(i.getPrice());
        commandes.add(pc);
    }               

    Collections.sort(commandes);
```

i wanna sort this object (commande) based on the date field so here's my object

```
public class Commande implements Comparable<Commande> {
    // other fields 
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") 
    LocalDate date;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Commande c) {
         return date.compareTo(c.getDate());
    }        
 }
```

the problem is that the objects o c.getCommandes() and the object i create and add in the for loop are kind of sorted separably

[image]

i don't know what i'm missing here, any suggestions
thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting the contents of that screen shot? How is it related to the `commandes` list and to `c.getCommandes()` list?

Answer (score 4):

That is because the list you sorted is not `c.getCommandes` but a new list you created:

```
List<Commande> commandes = new ArrayList<Commande>(c.getCommandes());
```

creates a new list that is not `c.getCommandes()` but is basically the copy of it.

If you want to modify the `c.getCommandes` list, do not create an other one and work directly on it:

```
List<Commande> commandes = c.getCommandes();
```

Comment: thanks fr the suggestion , but working directly the`c.getCommandes()` list wouldn't solve the problem because what i'm sorting is `List<Commande> commandes` this list and not `c.getCommandes()`

Comment: That is why is my last example I assign `commandes` to `c.getCommandes()` :) Try it, it should solve your issue!

Comment: yes i just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work, thanks for the help